# What does the ampersand sign(&) means in this method?

Tags: php, function, oop, orm

I'm learning the ORM and found a function here, what does the `&` instance do?

```
public static function & instance()
    {
        if(!self::$db)
        {
            self::$db = new DB;
        }
        return self::$db;
    }
```